# Is the realgg.nl exchange legit?

Tags: exchanges

I was on a site [www.realgg.nl](http://www.realgg.nl) last night, they have some attractive funding options for me because I live in UK it's difficult to get coins. (Well a lot more difficult than US). Just wondering if anyone knows whether it's legit.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not - terrible exhange for any type of (crypto) currency.

**DO NOT BUY HERE** - you will receive your coins late (I received mine after 3 days of placing my order) AND they used the exchange rate of the day and time of the processing of the order - in other words I lost 60% of my purchase because they were 'having problems with their system' and took 3 days to deliver.